# variable not initialized in the default constructor

Tags: java

I have the following code where i get the aforementioned error code when i try to import the repository class in the "private final Repository repository;" bit of code.

I have tried adding "private Object repository" but then i get a "variable repository is already defined in class restaurant controller" on the "private final repository repository". I also get a "cannot find symbol method store (string) location variable repository of type Object" wherever the 'repository.store' method is called.

```
package controllers;

import helpers.InputHelper;
import helpers.InputHelper;
import repositories.Repository;
import model.Restaurant;
import model.Review;


public class RestaurantController {
    InputHelper inputHelper = new InputHelper();
    char c = inputHelper.readCharacter("A:Restaurant Name -B: Review -C: Location -D: Rating");
    static char DELIMITER=',';
    **private final Repository repository;**


    public void run() {
        boolean quit = false;

        do {
            char choice = displayMenu();
            switch (choice) {
                case 'A': 
                    addRestaurant();
                    String name = inputHelper.readString("Enter Restaurant Name: ");               
                    repository.store(name); 
                    System.out.println("Restaurant Name is: " + name);

                    break;
                case 'B':  
                    addReview();
                    String review = inputHelper.readString("Enter Restaurant Review: ");               
                    repository.store(review); 
                    break;
                case 'C': 
                    listLocationRestaurantDataInNameOrder();
                    String location = inputHelper.readString("Enter Restaurant Location : ");               
                    repository.store(location); 
                    break;                    
                case 'D': 
                    listRestaurantRatings();
                    String rating = inputHelper.readString("Enter Restaurant Rating : ");               
                    repository.store(rating); 
                    break;
                case 'Q': 
                    quit = true;
            }
        } while (!quit);
    }

    private char displayMenu() {
        listRestaurantDataInIdOrder();
        InputHelper inputHelper = new InputHelper();
        System.out.print("\nA. Add Restaurant");
        System.out.print("\tB. Add Restaurant Review");        
        System.out.print("\tC. List Location Restaurant Data In Name Order");
        System.out.print("\tD. List Restaurant Ratings");       
        System.out.print("\tQ. Quit\n");         
        return inputHelper.readCharacter("Enter choice", "ABCDQ");
    }    

    private void addRestaurant() {
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Add Restaurant");
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "==============");

    }

    private void addReview() {        
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Add Restaurant Review");
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "=====================");       
    }    


    private void listLocationRestaurantDataInNameOrder() {        
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Name Order");
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "==========");
    }    

    private void listRestaurantRatings() {
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Restaurant Ratings");
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "==================");   
    }    

    private void listRestaurantDataInIdOrder() {        
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "Restaurant Id Order");
        System.out.format("\033[31m%s\033[0m%n", "===================");
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the controller with a Repository

```
public class RestaurantController {

    private final Repository repository;

    public RestaurantController(Repository r) {
        this.repository = r;
    }
```

Otherwise, you've defined an uninitialized final variable, which is not valid. You could remove `final`, but then the value would be `null`

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `repository` hence you are getting the error. You cannot call a method on a non-initialized object.